# grep pairs of patterns and file

Tags: linux, grep

I have a file (search.patterns) with a list of patterns to be searched into a list of other txt files.

search.patterns

```
home
dog 
cat
```

file 1.txt

```
home 3
tiger 4
lion 1
```

file 2.txt

```
dolphin 6
jaguar 3
dog 1
```

file 3.txt

```
donkey 3
cat 4
horse 1
```

so I want the first line of the pattern file to be searched in the file1, the second line searched in the file2 and the third line in file3

Output:

```
home 3
dog 1
cat 4
```

I have written some code like this:

```
for f in *.txt;
    do 
    while IFS= read -r LINE; 
        do grep -f "$LINE" "$f" > "$f.out"
    done < search.patterns
done
```

However, the output files are empty

Any help, highly appreciated,thanks

Comment: Are the files numbered like `file1.txt`, `file2.txt` or you just assumed them?

Comment: @msp9011 actually would be better to have only one joined file output, otherwise I can join later with cat command

Comment: @msp9011 the given data does not have home here but in my data there could be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `bash`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

files=( 'file 1.txt' 'file 2.txt' 'file 3.txt' )

while IFS= read -r pattern; do
    grep -e "$pattern" "${files[0]}"
    files=( "${files[@]:1}" )
done <search.patterns
```

Testing it:

```
$ bash script.sh
home 3
dog 1
cat 4
```

The script saves the relevant filenames in the `files` array, and then proceeds to read patterns from the `search.patterns` file.  For each pattern, the first file in the `files` list is queried.  The processed file is then deleted from the `files` list (yielding a new first filename in the list).

If the number of patterns exceeds the number of files in `files`, there will be errors from `grep`.

Comment: is it possible to write files=(file*.txt) as before? because I have 50 files and I cannot type each file name

Comment: by the way, does not seems to work...

Comment: actually, example of my file name is 5pop.chr1.20000_new.1.tree.txt 5pop.chr1.20000_new.2.tree.txt till 50...then there could be 5pop.chr1.30000_new.1.tree.txt 5pop.chr1.30000_new.2.tree.txt till 50, so I have m any files

Comment: files=(*.txt)
echo "${files[@]}"
while IFS= read -r pattern; do
    grep -e "$pattern" "${files[0]}"
    files=( "${files[@]:1}" )
done <search.patterns

Comment: the last code works

Answer (score 6):

With GNU awk (`gawk`) you could use a `BEGINFILE` rule to read a new pattern each time the input file changes:

```
$ gawk 'BEGINFILE{getline pat < "search.patterns"} $0 ~ pat' file\ {1..3}.txt
home 3
dog 1
cat 4
```

You should really check that `getline` returns a new pattern, for example

```
gawk '
  BEGINFILE {
    if((getline pat < "search.patterns") <= 0) {
      print "Error reading pattern" > "/dev/stderr"
      exit 1
    }
  } 
  $0 ~ pat
' file\ {1..3}.txt
```

Note that `awk` patterns are *extended* regular expressions, similar to those supported by `grep` with the `-E` option.

You could achieve the same in non-GNU `awk` by passing `search.patterns` as the first file and using `NR` and `FNR` appropriately to either read the patterns into an indexed array, or look up the next pattern in the array.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `paste` to match the pattern with the file:

```
paste <(printf "%s\n" *.txt) search.patterns | while IFS=$'\t' read -r file pattern; do
    grep -- "$pattern" "$file"
done
```

I'm assuming the filenames do not contain tabs.